# Is it possible to detect and do an action when user closes an Android/IOS Cordova/Capacitor App?

Tags: javascript, java, android, capacitor, quasar-framework

I'm developing an App with Capacitor and Quasar Framework. I wanted the app to log and close any pending notification from the app when the user closes the app(not background, really closing it by mobile interface like swiping right on "opened apps menu".
I'm using background to track geolocation, so "Terminate" event is not really when the app closes.

I tried using the `window.addEventListener("beforeunload")` and I developed a plugin in Java that tried to throw an event to a listener: `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook`, neither helped me handle that.

Is that something possible? I wanted to log the closing and check if there is a notification still showing to the user, so I can close it.

Capacitor Plugin code

```java
public void load() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("appClosed");
        JSObject ret = new JSObject();
        ret.put("appClosed", true);
        notifyListeners("appClosed", ret);
      }

    });
}
```

Comment: I would love to see if anyone has created any solutions for this.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: From my part, I gave up trying to hook this kind of event.
If I have an appending notification while on background and the app gets close not by the user, it stills inconsistent.
In the end, no user of the app really complains about this situation, that is kinda rare anyway, happens mostly when the device is hungry for more memory and my app was tracking geolocation, so it gets the first in the line for the killing.